# Divide by a certain position in R

Tags: r, dataframe, function, indexing, dplyr

I have several series, each one indicates the deflator for the GDP for each country. (Data attached down below)

So what I want to do is to divide every column for the 97th position.

I know this could be pretty simple for you, but I am struggling.

This is my code so far:

```
d_data <- d_data  %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, function(x) x/d_data[[97,x]])
```

So as you can see in the data, from columns 3 to 8 data are numeric.

I think the error is that argument x of the function refers to the column name, while in the `d_data`, the second argument refers to column position and that is the main issue.

How can I solve this? Thanks in advance!!

## Data

---

Data was massive to put here (745 rows, 8 columns)

So I uploaded the `dput(d_data)` output [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xaHp06XQqE8i_Rq_FcEmChSQiP_N9tFf/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mutate` with `across` as `_at/_all` are deprecated.  Also, to extract by position, use `nth`

```
library(dplyr)
d_data  %>% 
     mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ .x/nth(.x, 97)))
```

---

In the OP's code, instead of `d_data[[97,x]]`, it should be `x[97]` as `x` here is the column value itself

```
d_data  %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, function(x) x/x[97])
```

If we want to subset the original data column, have to pass either column index or column name. Here, `x` doesn't refer to column index or name.  But with `across`, we can get the column name with `cur_column()`  e.g. (`mtcars %>% summarise(across(everything(), ~ cur_column()))`) which is not needed for this case

Comment: this worked perfectly! but why is it `.x`? I am just curious.

Comment: @JorgeParedes with tidyverse, the lambda expression is concise `function(x)` is equivalent to `~` and the default symbol is `.x` to refer